# Twitter Bootstrap onclick event on buttons-radio

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-events

I have a Twitter Bootstrap buttons-radio and hook an onclick event to it. But how do I check which of the buttons that got triggered?

My first thought was to simply check for the class 'active', but this should create a race condition (result depends on whether the Twitter Bootstrap event or my own onclick event is handled first).

Answer (score 77, accepted):

This is a really annoying one. What I ended up using is this:

First, create a group of simple buttons with no `data-toggle` attribute.

```
<div id="selector" class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn active">Day</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn">Week</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn">Month</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn">Year</button>
</div>
```

Next, write an event handler that simulates the radio button effect by 'activating' the clicked one and 'deactivating' all other buttons. (EDIT: Integrated [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1157545/nick)'s cleaner version from the comments.)

```
$('#selector button').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    // TODO: insert whatever you want to do with $(this) here
});
```

Comment: A slightly concise and optimized (no double call to selector) version: $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

Comment: this doesn't work with radio button. how to specify which one is which if each radio button does different thing

Comment: @MurhafSousli I'm not sure I understand your problem. If you insert your code where I put the `// TODO`, you should be able to access the freshly selected radio button as `$(this)`.

Comment: @Nick I really like your solution, so I decided to integrate it into the answer, to give it a bit more spotlight. Hope you don't mind!

Comment: Improvement: It is better to use mousedown event, because the colors of the buttons change on mousedown (incomplete click).

Comment: In most cases nobody will do an incomplete click on the button (like pressing the mouse and then moving cursor away while still holding it), but if somebody does, it will appear they have two buttons selected

Comment: There's really no need to override the default bootstrap handling of css classes, try this solution instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28603203/729324

Comment: Really annoying issue and this solution helped me. Using Angular 5 and Bootstrap toggle button. I think having a click event and data-toggle in same input was the problem. Removing data-toggle fixed the issue. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 77):

I see a lot of complicated answers, while this is super simple in Bootstrap 3:

Step 1: Use [the official example code](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio) to create your radio button group, and give the container an id:

```
<div id="myButtons" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Radio 1 (preselected)
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Radio 3
  </label>
</div>
```

Step 2: Use this jQuery handler:

```
$("#myButtons :input").change(function() {
    console.log(this); // points to the clicked input button
});
```

[Try the fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9k8oc5pf/1/)

Comment: This is the best solution I agree.

Comment: @bonez I've added a fiddle, please elaborate why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Came across this whilst looking for the solution, in this instance have your fiddle look for the checked condition of the put ```console.log($(this).is(':checked'));``` into the function and watch the results. 

Now click on the pre selected check - it returns false every time. Now check another button - oh look, true, now click the same button again - back to false. So not really an ideal solution.

Comment: On my latest Chrome, this works fine. Here's an updated fiddle that I used to test this: https://jsfiddle.net/9k8oc5pf/109/. In what browser does this fail?

Comment: @SgtOddball The problem you noticed was fixed a few years back, https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/11376 (the fiddle is still using 3.0.0, sorry)

Answer (score 23):

I would use a change event not a click like this:

```
$('input[name="name-of-radio-group"]').change( function() {
  alert($(this).val())
})
```

Comment: Thought about that but according to w3schools (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) the onchange event is only triggered by <input>, <select>, <textarea>. And <input type="button"> is different from Twitters recommended <button>.

Comment: This only works in Chrome: Firefox and other browsers will not trigger the change event due to the way Bootrap (at least as of 3.0) works.

Comment: On the latest docs (3.0) Bootstrap seems to recommend using input type="checkbox" for the grouped buttons: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-examples

Answer (score 9):

**For Bootstrap 3** the default radio/button-group structure is :

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1"> Option 1
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2"> Option 2
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3"> Option 3
    </label>
</div>
```

And you can select the active one like this:

```
$('.btn-primary').on('click', function(){
    alert($(this).find('input').attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: Why use the `id` field for a value when an input has a `value` attribute?

Answer (score 6):

Don't use data-toggle attribute so that you can control the toggle behavior by yourself. So it will avoid 'race-condition'

my codes:

button group template (written in .erb, embedded ruby for ruby on rails):

```
<div class="btn-group" id="featuresFilter">
     <% _.each(features, function(feature) { %> <button class="btn btn-primary" data="<%= feature %>"><%= feature %></button> <% }); %>
</div>
```

and javascript:

```
onChangeFeatures = function(e){
        var el=e.target;
        $(el).button('toggle');

        var features=el.parentElement;
        var activeFeatures=$(features).find(".active");
        console.log(activeFeatures);
}
```

onChangeFeatures function will be triggered once the button is clicked.

Comment: This helped me... I was running into an issue where my click handler would go off before the bootstrap library changed the toggle state of my button - so my code always thought the button was toggled. Definitely better to handle the toggle by yourself in more complex situations.

Comment: Technically, there is no [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) in this scenario.

Answer (score 3):

I needed to do the same thing for a chart where you could select the period of the data that should be displayed.

Therefore I introduced the CSS class 'btn-group-radio' and used the following unobtrusive javascript one-liner:

```
// application.js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn-group-radio .btn').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings('.btn').removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<!-- some arbitrary view -->
<div class="btn-group btn-group-radio">
  <%= link_to '1W', charts_path('1W'), class: 'btn btn-default active', remote: true %>
  <%= link_to '1M', charts_path('1M'), class: 'btn btn-default', remote: true %>
  <%= link_to '3M', charts_path('3M'), class: 'btn btn-default', remote: true %>
  <%= link_to '6M', charts_path('6M'), class: 'btn btn-default', remote: true %>
  <%= link_to '1Y', charts_path('1Y'), class: 'btn btn-default', remote: true %>
  <%= link_to 'All', charts_path('all'), class: 'btn btn-default', remote: true %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the example HTML for radio buttons on the Twitter Bootstrap page (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms), you can see that each input has a unique ID attribute, i.e. `optionsRadios1` and `optionsRadios2`.

The relevant HTML example snippet is included here for completeness:

```
<div class="controls">
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" checked="" value="option1" id="optionsRadios1" name="optionsRadios">
    Option one is this and that—be sure to include why it's great
  </label>
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" value="option2" id="optionsRadios2" name="optionsRadios">
    Option two can is something else and selecting it will deselect option one
  </label>
</div>
```

So you can use a jQuery click event, and then use the `this` reference to look at the id of the HTML element that was clicked.

```
$('.controls').find('input').bind('click',function(event){
  if($(this).attr('id')==='optionsRadios1'){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
  } else {
    //... call some other function
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If your html is similar to the example, so the click event is produced over the label, not in the input, so I use the next code:
**Html example:**

```
<div id="myButtons" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Radio 1 (preselected)
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio 2
  </label>      
</div>
```

**Javascript code for the event:**

```
$('#option1').parent().on("click", function () {
   alert("click fired"); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer to this question! Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, because a code dump with no context doesn't explain how or why the solution will work, making it difficult for the original poster (or any future readers) to understand the logic behind it. Please, edit your question and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I searched so many pages: I found a beautiful solution. Check it out:

[git link](https://github.com/sajibremix/PHP-Section/blob/master/bootstrap_toogle_event_handle.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#my_launch_today_chk").change(function() {
                var chk = $(this).prop('checked');
                if(chk == true){
                    console.log("On");
                }else{
                    console.log("OFF");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body >

<input type="checkbox" id="my_launch_today_chk" checked data-on="Launch" data-off="OFF" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="small">
</body>
</html>
```