# Getting active buttons in button-group (bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a button group and am willing to update some other field on change according to the active buttons. 
See the [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/hA423/4/)

This is the HTML, copied from the documentation:

```
<div class="btn-group arrActiviteit arrUpdate" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary active" data-wat='foo'>
       <input type="checkbox"> Item 1
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" data-wat='bar'>
       <input type="checkbox"> Item 2
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" data-wat='something'>
      <input type="checkbox"> item 3
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" data-wat='orElse'>
      <input type="checkbox"> item 4
    </label>
</div>
```

The Button row acts like it should do.
Then I watch for a click event on the `.arrUpdate` div for change. I've got multiple button groups which all have the `.arrUpdate` class. That's the reason for the second class: `.arrActiviteit`

```
$('.arrUpdate').click(function(e){
   val = ''; // for holding the temporary values

   $('.arrActiviteit label').each(function(key, value){
       if(value.className.indexOf('active') >=0){
           val += value.dataset.wat
       }
   })

   // just for debug reasons.
   $('#hierHier').html(val); 

})
```

But it appears that the 'active' class gets added *after* the click event is fired. So the value in `#hierHier` is always behind one click, so to say.

**How can I resolve this?

Or is there a better way to retrieve all the active buttons in this checkbox-array?**

Comment: put your code here http://jsfiddle.net/hA423/2/ so that we can figure out the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED

---

update: better solution [Twitter Bootstrap onclick event on buttons-radio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262827/twitter-bootstrap-onclick-event-on-buttons-radio)

---

http://jsfiddle.net/hA423/7/

I solved it using a timeout to make your function run after bootstrap events...

There must be some other ways to do it...

```
$('.btn').on('click',function(e){
  setTimeout(count);
})
```

Comment: See this thread here for a better solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262827/twitter-bootstrap-onclick-event-on-buttons-radio

Comment: but which answer do you consider the better one?  there's a lot of choice in there!

Comment: go for the other one ... trust me