# Bootstrap 3 btn-group lose active class when click anywhere on the page

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, focus

I am working on the [following demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/fzdfJ/1/). I am looking to discover why btn-group is losing Active class whenever I click any where on the page.

I was expecting the btn-group toggle only between each other. Did I do any thing wrong here?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="well">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="regi1">Left</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="regi2">Middle</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="regi3">Right</button>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The only reason I could imagine this is happening would be some JavaScript getting executed on click that is removing the class.  Do you have any relevant JavaScript to share?

Comment: Have you used any external css ?I think stat30 is right.It also can happen for css fault.I am not sure,please give more details.

Comment: That gray fill that appear when you click on a button isn't actually the application of an "active" class (there isn't one) - it's actually the focus behaviour of the button. (You know, like how hyperlinks have that dotted outline to show that they're being focused.) Try pressing Tab after clicking a button, and you should see the focus selection move to a different element. If you wanted an active class to be used, just write a snippet of jQuery to apply/remove the class when clicking buttons in the group. (Or use Bootstrap tabs!) If you want to see a jQuery example, let me know.

Comment: everything is on that demo, no extra jquery or css!

Comment: @Serlite thanks but how can I do that? I mean I like to keep first button clicked/pressed/active until the other button clicked not from other part of page click! oh my god I used lots of click !

Comment: I'll add it as an answer below. (Probably shouldn't post code in the comments. XD)

Comment: For those coming late to the party here, the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio) actually refers to having to manually update the class if you're using an external click handler and not the data-toggle method.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

So, (as mentioned in the comments) that gray fill you see isn't actually an active class being applied - it's the focus selection behaviour of that particular Bootstrap button element. (Like the dotted outline of a hyperlink.) Try pressing Tab after clicking a button, and you should see the focus selection change.

One way to get the behaviour you want is to apply the active class yourself, and have a bit of jQuery to swap the active class when clicking a button in the group. Here's what the snippet might look like:

```
$(".btn-group > .btn").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});
```

The code above removes the active class from all `.btn` elements in the `.btn-group`, then applies the active class to the one that was just clicked.

Here's a [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fzdfJ/2/) to show you what this achieves (note that I coded the first button to have the active class in the HTML to start with). If this isn't what you were looking for, let me know and I'll be happy to help further. Good luck!

Comment: From [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262827), you want to do `$(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");` instead of re-running the selector. The way you have it, clicking any button removes the `active` class from other `btn-group`s on the page. Compare http://jsfiddle.net/fzdfJ/67/ to http://jsfiddle.net/fzdfJ/68/

Answer (score -1):

I came here looking for an Angular solution. The `ng-class` is what prevents the deselection on blur.

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-warning"
        ng-class="o.value == myinput.selected_value? 'active':''"
        ng-repeat="o in options">
    <input type="radio"
        autocomplete="off" 
        ng-value="{{o.value}}"
        ng-model="myinput.selected_value">
    {{o.value)}}
  </label>
</div>
```