# OnClick event on hidden radio button

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

I am using bootstrap. Where on UI, I have to display multiple button which should behave as radio button.

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" onclick="javascript:a();" autocomplete="off" style="display:none;"/> Radio 1
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" onclick="javascript:a();" autocomplete="off" style="display:none;"/> Radio 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" onclick="javascript:a();" autocomplete="off" style="display:none;"/> Radio 3
  </label>
</div>
```

I want to call an onclick function on click of those buttons. But doesn't seem to be working.

```
function a(){
alert("test");
}
```

Any idea, how can I achieve that. Any alternate way will also be welcomed. Thanks!

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

Comment: Seems like you have forgotten " in `onclick="javascript:a();`, for option2 and option3

Comment: And also you forgot to close the tags input, like this one `<input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" onclick="javascript:a();" autocomplete="off" checked> Radio 1 (preselected)`

Comment: Please don't downvote. This is just a sample code. I will edit with complete info.

Comment: It was me who downvoted it. But you should definetely review your HTML. Try to put it inside a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and test it.

Comment: Don't think closing input is mandatory. Anyway. Thats not the cause of problem. Check out the image attached

Comment: That's alright. As you can see, I am still crawling ;)

Comment: It is mandatory and also a good practice to close all your tags.

Comment: What is also a good practice is to bind handlers using JQuery instead of inline handlers

Comment: Check out this Fiddle with a solution for you: http://jsfiddle.net/jotamartins/gcomemqe/

Answer (score 2):

From this page: [Twitter Bootstrap onclick event on buttons-radio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262827/twitter-bootstrap-onclick-event-on-buttons-radio)

```
$('input[name="options"]').change( function() {
  alert("test");
})
```

If you want to retrieve the value from the checked radio button you have to add to every radio button:

```
value="myValue"
```

And you can retrieve this value with:

```
  alert($(this).val());
```

Answer (score 1):

It is always a good practice to bind your click handler using JQuery instead of inline handlers, like this:

```
$(function(){
    $("input[name='options']").click(a);
});

function a(){
    alert("test");   
}
```

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jotamartins/gcomemqe/1/)

Comment: This will work. But My problem is this onclick I am calling inside multiple javascript loops and onclick function is taking multiple parameter based on the loop value. I am able to select those input radio which is of button type UI, but I am suspecting due to display:none property it is unable to call the onclick method.

Any alternate way to do this ?

Comment: Why do you need a 'display:none'? With this property you won't be able even to click the radio button.

Comment: What kind of parameters do you need to pass?

Comment: I do not want radio button sign to be displayed on UI. Without display:none,I am getting radio button inside a button. Which I do not need. :/ Without display:none, It is working. Just checked

Comment: I am getting lots of data via ajax call in json format. which I am iterating and then I am creating buttons on UI. Those iterated value i am adding in onclick parameter which I am receiving in function and then calling something else.

Comment: I don't actually see where you have another button in your code besides the radio button. But it seems to be a bad workaround for your problem.

Comment: Seems like your problem is way bigger than your original question. You should update it or create another one. Because this one has already been answered.

Comment: Check the image attached in my question. Exactly same way I am getting buttons. Thanks for your answers though

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way by jQuery

```
$('[name="options"]').click(function() {
    alert('test')
})
```

You can use `data` attributes for passing parameters

```
<input type="radio" name="options" data-foo="1" data-bar="2" />
```

and jQuery will be

```
$('[name="options"]').click(function() {
        alert($(this).data('foo'))
        alert($(this).data('bar'))
    })
```

Comment: Problem is, In my actual code I am passing multiple parameter inside that function. which may not be available this way.

Comment: you can use data attributes